# Did you enjoy vs Did you enjoyed

Tags: verb-forms, past-participles

> Did you **enjoy** the snow?**
>
> Did you **enjoyed** the snow?**

What is the difference between these two sentences? For example, today it was snowing, so if I want to ask someone whether they enjoyed it, what should I say?

Thanks!!

Comment: The second sentence is wrong....

Answer (score 0):

> Did you enjoy the snow?

For an *Indirect Question*, like when you do not start your question with a question word, *then* you can use the past-tense:

> You enjoyed the snow, right?

The same goes for exclamations:

> You enjoyed the snow!?

But for your standard, vanilla question words, you stick with the root word:

> How did you enjoy the snow?
>
> What did you enjoy?
>
> Where did you enjoy the snow?
>
> When did you enjoy the snow?

...the list goes on...

Answer (score 0):

You would ask someone

> **Did you enjoy the snow?**

meaning did they **have fun** in the snow, did the snow and possible activities **around** the snow bring you **pleasure**.

> Did you **like** the snow?

might be used to **reference more** the experience of the snow itself

Your Mom might ask

> **Did you like your dinner?**

if she wanted to know what you thought of her cooking.
A friend might ask

> Did you **enjoy** your dinner?

meaning did you like the food, the drink, whatever conversation you may have had, may music, **the entire setting**

The second sentence is grammatically incorrect.